# Java Application Code Isolation

Tags: java, performance, tomcat

I have a framework where customer can develop their applications. The framework is a Java based application which runs under the Tomcat container and loads the custom applications.
We test our application with the sample application for a huge load and it passes the load, but where developers load their custom application and when a custom application leaks memory or messes up with threads etc, it effects my application and when their load test fails they ended up blaming my application for leaks and we end up fixing their application.
Is there a mechanism / framework I can use so that my framework runs in a separate process space without doing much design change and customer application runs on separate. So that my app does not crash when customer messes up with the applicaition.

Comment: So, you need to run untrusted code in a safe way? Yikes. The only real fool-proof way is process-isolation, where your code runs in one JVM and theirs runs in another. Java isn't great at running child processes. I think you need to re-think your deployment model.

Comment: I'd suggest deploying a separate tomcat container for each application. Both applications can be made accessible via a proxy that frontends incoming requests. When a third application is deployed, you simply spawn a new container for that too, and update proxy configuration dynamically. I'd expect nginx to handle such runtime configuration, much better than httpd. YMMV.